Java Instant can't able to save in mysql column of type Timestamp through Spring JPA
I am trying to save java Instant type in mysql column of Timestamp type.But I am getting MysqlDataTruncation exception as shown below. Though the column allows Null value, when I try to pass Null value for the same column. Still I am getting same exception
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1732583454.419425000' for column 'created_at' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:194)
    ... 151 common frames omitted

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Based on the value that is in the log output, 1732583454.419425000, you've got nanosecond precision, MySql might not be able to store.  Can you try truncating the timestamp by using timestampInstant.truncateTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS) where you pass the timestamp to the persistence layer.
